# How to get the last row Id after insert data into table for SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-7, winrt-xaml

I am using SQLite and SQLite-Net Wrapper for WinRT app. Other platform may have SQLite, but the implementation may be different such as using SQLite-Net api.

How do I get the last row Id immediately after insert for SQLite? Thanks

```
 using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(DBPath))
            {
                var newOrder = new SalesOrder()
                {
                    CustId = g_intCustId,
                    Customer_No = txtBlkCustomer.Text.Trim(),
                    Order_Date = DateTime.Today                    
                };

                db.Insert(newOrder);

      }

--1--- Update : I am using SQLite-Net Wrapper. I am not using SQLite -WInRT


I get the following error :

The type arguments for method 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection.ExecuteScalar(string, params object[])' 

cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.    

db.Insert(newOrder);
var key = db.ExecuteScalar("SELECT last_insert_rowid()");


---2-- Update 


This is the class :

My problem is : How to get the SId immediately after inserting a record using above code.

 class SalesOrder
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int SId { get; set; }  

        public int CustId { get; set; }
        public string Customer_No { get; set; }
        public DateTime  Order_Date { get; set; }

     }
```

Comment: @juergend This is not PHP.

Comment: This is using SQLite-Net in WinRT.

Comment: I am a little puzzled that a *C#* question is being closed as a dup of a *PHP* question.

Comment: @MilkBottle I have the same question as you had , but im not able to figure out how to change the code ? where am i supposed to find the SQLite.cs file i am using nuget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [SQLite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs#L1219), `Insert` method returns the number of row inserted (SQLite.cs). So if you want it to return the last row ID you can update it to do like that.

Current implementation.

```
public int Insert (object obj, string extra, Type objType)
{
    if (obj == null || objType == null) {
        return 0;
    }


    var map = GetMapping (objType);

    #if NETFX_CORE
    if (map.PK != null && map.PK.IsAutoGuid)
    {
        // no GetProperty so search our way up the inheritance chain till we find it
        PropertyInfo prop;
        while (objType != null)
        {
            var info = objType.GetTypeInfo();
            prop = info.GetDeclaredProperty(map.PK.PropertyName);
            if (prop != null) 
            {
                if (prop.GetValue(obj, null).Equals(Guid.Empty))
                {
                    prop.SetValue(obj, Guid.NewGuid(), null);
                }
                break; 
            }

            objType = info.BaseType;
        }
    }
    #else
    if (map.PK != null && map.PK.IsAutoGuid) {
        var prop = objType.GetProperty(map.PK.PropertyName);
        if (prop != null) {
            if (prop.GetValue(obj, null).Equals(Guid.Empty)) {
                prop.SetValue(obj, Guid.NewGuid(), null);
            }
        }
    }
    #endif


    var replacing = string.Compare (extra, "OR REPLACE", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0;

    var cols = replacing ? map.InsertOrReplaceColumns : map.InsertColumns;
    var vals = new object[cols.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < vals.Length; i++) {
        vals [i] = cols [i].GetValue (obj);
    }

    var insertCmd = map.GetInsertCommand (this, extra);
    var count = insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery (vals);

    if (map.HasAutoIncPK)
    {
        var id = SQLite3.LastInsertRowid (Handle);
        map.SetAutoIncPK (obj, id);
    }

    return count;
}
```

Updated implementation.

```
public int Insert (object obj, string extra, Type objType)
{
    if (obj == null || objType == null) {
        return 0;
    }


    var map = GetMapping (objType);

    #if NETFX_CORE
    if (map.PK != null && map.PK.IsAutoGuid)
    {
        // no GetProperty so search our way up the inheritance chain till we find it
        PropertyInfo prop;
        while (objType != null)
        {
            var info = objType.GetTypeInfo();
            prop = info.GetDeclaredProperty(map.PK.PropertyName);
            if (prop != null) 
            {
                if (prop.GetValue(obj, null).Equals(Guid.Empty))
                {
                    prop.SetValue(obj, Guid.NewGuid(), null);
                }
                break; 
            }

            objType = info.BaseType;
        }
    }
    #else
    if (map.PK != null && map.PK.IsAutoGuid) {
        var prop = objType.GetProperty(map.PK.PropertyName);
        if (prop != null) {
            if (prop.GetValue(obj, null).Equals(Guid.Empty)) {
                prop.SetValue(obj, Guid.NewGuid(), null);
            }
        }
    }
    #endif


    var replacing = string.Compare (extra, "OR REPLACE", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0;

    var cols = replacing ? map.InsertOrReplaceColumns : map.InsertColumns;
    var vals = new object[cols.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < vals.Length; i++) {
        vals [i] = cols [i].GetValue (obj);
    }

    var insertCmd = map.GetInsertCommand (this, extra);
    var count = insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery (vals);
    long id = 0;    //New line
    if (map.HasAutoIncPK)
    {
        id = SQLite3.LastInsertRowid (Handle);  //Updated line
        map.SetAutoIncPK (obj, id);
    }

    //Updated lines
    //return count; //count is row affected, id is primary key
    return (int)id;
    //Updated lines
}
```

Comment: I need to do this: Insert a record in a table and get the Primary Key of the table IMMEDIATELY for this record. Above code, I use db.Insert(newOrder), then Int Id = newOrder.SId where SId is the primary Key in that table, is this method correct?

Comment: If you use my solution & `var ID = db.Insert(newOrder);` then ID will be `SId`, that's your primary key & auto increment column.

Comment: I think the ID in var ID = db.Insert(newOrder) is Not the Primary Key as it always return 1. I tried this Int Id = newOrder.SId, where Id is different each time I create a new record. Can you confirm this? Thanks :)

Comment: Have you changed SQLite.cs according to my solution?

Comment: It is Ok to use this  Int Id = newOrder.SId  Will this be any different than your solution .

Comment: No it's same, but if you use my solution then you don't have to write line `Id = newOrder.SId` because it will return the ID.

Comment: @Xyroid i am not able to find any procedure on how to edit nuget packages /libraries , simple right clicking and goto implementation is not briniging up the metheods only properties.Where to find SQLite.cs file ?

Answer (score 7):

do you have the ExecuteScalar method on your connection? then use

```
var key = db.ExecuteScalar<int>("SELECT last_insert_rowid()");
```

Comment: I got the above error. What I did wrong? I am using SQLite-Net

Comment: Don't you have to do something like `...ExecuteScalar("...", new [] object)`?

Comment: I just installed the package, and it worked. Also, what does id in "var id = db.Insert(newOrder);" return? It seems to return the identity of the inserted record. Is your identity column an int type?